# How to access array within array in json in angular

Tags: angular

I want to access array within array in json in my component.ts.I tried with normal for loop but I am not able access it.I also tried foreach but it gives error.I want to access profiletypes in my component.ts file.I got error at  for(let profile in experience).
please give me solution

json file

```
"Experiences": [ {
            "ExperienceId": 1,
            "Title": "GIS Analyst",
            "ExperienceType": "Professional",
            "FromDate": "2011-05-04",
            "TodaysDate": "2011-05-06",
            "Renumerations": ["20","50"],
            "Organization" :{
                "OraganizationId": 1,
                "OrganizationName": "Here",
                "Location": "Airoli"
            },
            "Profiles" :[ {
                    "Title": "Hi",
                    "ProfileType": "Operations", 
                    "FromDate": "2011-05-04",
                    "ToDate": "2011-05-04",
                    "CustomerName": "Here",
                    "Location": "Airoli",
                    "Roles": [{
                        "RoleName": "Data analysis",
                        "Responsibilities": [{
                            "ResponsibilityId": 1,
                            "Responsibility": "Find requirements",
                            "Description": "It is the practice of finding the requirements"
                        }]
                    }
                ]
                }]
            }]
```

component.ts

```
 this.personListService. getExperienceDetail()
     .subscribe(
      resp =>{ 
       this.experiences = resp.Experiences,
 var i,j;
          for(i=0;i<this.experiences.length;i++)
          {
            this.experiencetypes[i]=this.experiences[i].ExperienceType
            this.fromdateexps[i]=new Date(this.experiences[i].FromDate)
            this.todateexps[i]=new Date(this.experiences[i].TodaysDate)

            //this.rangeValues[i]=Number(this.experiences[i].Renumeration)

          }
       for(let experience in this.experiences)
       {
        for(let profile in experience)
        {
          this.profiletypes[i]=this.experiences[i].Profile[j].ProfileType
          console.log(this.profiletypes) 
        }
       }
```

Comment: Is that second for loop in the correct position? The variable `i` is only applicable inside first loop and variable `j` is not defined at all. And `profiletypes` will be a two dimensional array.

Comment: yes it is in right position

Comment: give me correct solution in your way I am confused while coding

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple of errors.

```
var i,j number; 

for(i=0;i<this.experiences.length;i++){

    this.experiencetypes[i]=this.experiences[i].ExperienceType
    this.fromdateexps[i]=new Date(this.experiences[i].FromDate)
    this.todateexps[i]=new Date(this.experiences[i].TodaysDate)
    //this.rangeValues[i]=Number(this.experiences[i].Renumeration)

    for(j=0;j<this.experiences[i].Profile.length;j++){

        this.profiletypes[i][j]=this.experiences[i].Profile[j].ProfileType
        console.log(this.profiletypes) 

    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error Property 'Profiles' does not exist on type 'Experience' at for(j=0;j<this.experiences[i].Profiles.length;j++)  at "Profiles"

Comment: Corrected. Your JSON sample had _Profiles_ instead of _Profile_.

Comment: errors.js:55 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - getting another error

Comment: Initialize your variables. `this.experiences = []`